# How to show that the normalizer N of a Sylow $p$-subgroup P of $S_p$ in $S_p$ is the affine linear group AGL(1,$p$)?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, normal-subgroups

I want to prove this as a special case of another fact that the normalizer of G in the group of set-bijections of G is isomorphic to the semi-direct product of Aut(G) and G itself. How do I link up the two things and prove them?

Comment: What goes wrong, if you try to apply that with $G=C_p$?

Comment: Oh I see, but what about the semi-direct product? Once the normalizer has been shown to be the semi-direct product, I think taking $G$=$C_p$ does the job, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. If you view $C_p$ as the additive group $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, then its automorphisms come from multiplying by an integer in the range $[1,p-1]$ (multiplication modulo $p$). You can then check what kind of cycles those multiplications correspond to.

Comment: Another route to the same destination would be to observe that if $\alpha$ is a $p$-cycle (= a generator of a group isomorphic to $C_p$), then its non-trivial powers are also $p$-cycles. All $p$-cycles are conjugates in $S_p$, so to each exponent $i, 1\le i\le p-1$ we have a permutation $\beta_i$ such that 
$$\beta_i\alpha\beta_i^{-1}=\alpha^i.$$ Also, the theory of conjugation in $S_p$ tells you that (a nice exercise!) that a $p$-cycle does not commute with permutations other than its powers. Thus $\beta_i$ above is unique up to a factor that is a power of $\alpha$.